# How to bind a command and data in a single control?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I am writing a custom control for a project. The control will hold a dropdown combobox and a datagrid. This control will be used throughout the project.  On the control I am exposing the SelectedDate and the SelectedDateChangedCommand as dependency properties. When the user selects a date the main programs Model would update it's list of information for the relevant date.

When I use that control in my project the data (SelectedDate) should come from the model but the command (SelectedDateChangedCommand) should come from the ViewModel. How do I bind the data to the Model and the command to the ViewModel?

Basically, if I want to bind the content AND command of the same button, what do I do?

**EDIT:**
Ok, I don't think I'm explaining this very well. I'm not using a framework or template or anything like that. Maybe my problem was mentioning the UserControl. My issue is not in writing the UserControl. My issue is from the outside of the control. I don't have a code example because that is my question: how do I do this? If I were to have some sort of code it would be like this:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Model.SelectedDate]" Command="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedDateChanged}" />
```

How do I bind two properties on a control that are on two different classes?

Wow, even *asking* questions is difficult in WPF. :)

Comment: How about adding another DP for command parameter, like WPF's [`Button.CommandParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.commandparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Hi, are you creating a usercontrol with codebehind(dp) and at the same time using a viewmodel as datacontext? Or have you created a custom control? Could you please post your code?

Comment: @Stígandr I hope the above edits help. I am creating (what I hope is) a stand-alone custom control. I am using that control in my project to display data. Think of the content AND command of a button. How do you bind both of those?

Comment: @TomPadilla could you please post your xaml and .cs? I used to do this a bit corny at first, bind a command in a control in the template of the cc, then just invoke a new command that's exposed and bound to your vm. I'm moved away from this, and instead used the controls directly grabbing them in OnApplyTemplate, then just fire Commands from the cc to the vm basicly. Well anyhow, if you post your code it would help us help you =)

Answer (score 0):

Ok if I understand you, you want to create a cc. Then Run bind to DateTime to your SelectedDate on your vm, and invoke a command from the control to the vm? I made a simple example for you here, I hope I understood you correctly. I simplified this example by just using a datepicker. I am using galasoft MVVM Light here. Change the content to what you want. Hope I didn't get you completely wrong :)

**Generic.xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:YourCustControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:YourCustControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid >
                        <DatePicker x:Name="PART_DatePicker"
                           SelectedDate="{Binding Path=YourDateTime, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:YourCustControl}}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**CustControl**

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_DatePicker", Type = typeof (DatePicker))]
public class YourCustControl : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateChangedCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedDateChangedCommand", typeof (ICommand), typeof (YourCustControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty YourDateTimeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("YourDateTime", typeof (DateTime), typeof (YourCustControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    private DatePicker datePicker;

    static YourCustControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof (YourCustControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof (YourCustControl)));
    }

    public ICommand SelectedDateChangedCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand) GetValue(SelectedDateChangedCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedDateChangedCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public DateTime YourDateTime
    {
        get { return (DateTime) GetValue(YourDateTimeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(YourDateTimeProperty, value); }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        datePicker = (DatePicker) Template.FindName("PART_DatePicker", this);
        if (datePicker != null)
        {
            datePicker.SelectedDateChanged += datePicker_SelectedDateChanged;
        }
    }

    private void datePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Execute the command
        if (SelectedDateChangedCommand != null && SelectedDateChangedCommand.CanExecute(e) && !e.Handled)
            SelectedDateChangedCommand.Execute(e);
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
// replace with whatever, like extend Galasoft's ViewModelBase 
public class YourViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator] // Remove if no R#
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class YourViewModel : YourViewModelBase
{
    private DateTime dateTime;

    public DateTime DateTime
    {
        get { return dateTime; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(dateTime)) return;
            dateTime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand SelectedDateChangedCommand { get; set; }

    public YourViewModel()
    {
        SelectedDateChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(OnSelectedDateChanged);
    }

    private void OnSelectedDateChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e != null)
            e.Handled = true; // dirty hack
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

**Finally your xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <local:YourCustControl SelectedDateChangedCommand="{Binding SelectedDateChangedCommand}" 
                           YourDateTime="{Binding DateTime, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

Hope it helps!

Cheers

Comment: OK, I'm not using a template or anything like that (my UserControl is way more complicated than a template can handle). And I'm not using an MVVM framework or anything.
But I see you have the DateTime and the SelectedDateChangedCommand both on the ViewModel. Is this the correct approach? Shouldn't DateTime be on the Model? And, if it is, how do you bind the DateTime on the Model AND the SelectedDateChangedCommand on the ViewModel at the same time?